# Add to bookmark on browser automatic using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to perform add to bookmark action using JavaScript or Jquery on on-load event.

Comment: Please share your code or effort to get help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't … for obvious security reasons. The user gets to choose what is added to their bookmarks, not the websites they visit. If it was otherwise, everyone's bookmarks would be indistinguishable from their browser history.